# Upload images and give list of URLs?

Tags: images, markdown

Does anyone know of a good tool/service that will allow me to upload a bunch of images to some free hosting service and then automatically provide me with a list of all the image URLs?

imgur.com is a great service that allows you to upload images and host them for free, but you have to grab image URLs individually. It would be great to have a service that would just give me a list of all the image URLs. (Bonus points if it could give me the image URLs in Markdown format!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could set up an ftp server  go to it e.g. if your ftp service were called - in theory - mojoftpserver, then they may give you one, you access in windows ftp://petersala.mojoftpserver.com

then drag the files to the ftp server, and access them

```
http://petersala.mojoftpserver.com/gorillas.jpg
http://petersala.mojoftpserver.com/flyingbats.jpg
http://petersala.mojoftpserver.com/dogs.jpg
```

so, the URL is easy to generate.. it all has the same base, then it's just the filename.

there seem to be less free ftp services around these days.. maybe many people use things like dropbox but i'm not aware of that listing URLs.

Your ISP may give you an FTP Server.  It may not be that anonymous though.. as you only have the one username, one address it's not like you get a random URL